Integrating Cognito User Pool Google Identity Provider into React Native iOS App
I have set up a user pool in AWS Cognito and added Google as an identity provider. Currently, I'm able to sign in with Google using the hosted UI provided by Cognito.
Now, I'm trying to integrate this Google sign-in functionality into my React Native iOS application. I've been searching for solutions for the past two days but haven't found a suitable implementation.
Specifically, I want to incorporate a Google sign-in button into my React Native app, which authenticates users through the Cognito user pool. Once a user signs in through this button, I need their data to be reflected in the Cognito user pool's user dashboard.
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this integration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
